# Concatenate preprocessor tokens

Tags: c, concatenation, c-preprocessor, c99

How to write a macro `#define CONCATENATE(x)` that will produce the following results:

```
CONCATENATE(int); // Produce --> int
CONCATENATE(unsigned int); // Produce --> unsignedint
CONCATENATE(long long int); // Produce --> longlongint
etc.
```

The result can be different than what I've written above. The only requirement is that the result is a single token. I need it to be a single token because this token will be used to define a function with name containing this token, for example `void Foo_longlongint(void);`

###### EDIT

I want to create generic functions using some macro trickery. For example lets say we want to declare a generic buffer:

```
#define DECLARE(type, size) struct {type buffer[size];}
```

Now I want to create functions for many possible types, for example:

```
#define DEFINE_FUNCTION(type)                                 \
void Buffer_##type##_Add(size_t idx, type *buffer, type data) \
{                                                             \
    buffer[idx] = data;                                       \
}
```

Comment: Why not use `stdint.h` types instead? `int64_t` is easier to deal with than `long long`, and also a lot more consistent between compilers.

Comment: I need this to work also with `struct Foo`, `enum Foo`, `union Foo`.

Comment: This sound s like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to strip whitespace at compile-time.  I think you need a different solution.

Comment: I am stuck on C99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conventional way to do this is to use the types from `stdint.h`, which do not have whitespace in them.  Names such as `uint32_t` and `int16_t`.

This will still be difficult if you want to incorporate `struct Foo` and `enum Foo`, but its a good starting point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAKE_FUNC(func_name, ret_type)                        \
ret_type##_t func_name##_##ret_type( void* alpha, int beta ) { \
    ret_type##_t ret_value;                                     \
    return ret_value; }

MAKE_FUNC(test, uint32) // Declares test_uint32 with return type uint32_t
MAKE_FUNC(test, int16)  // Declares test_int16 with return type int16_t

int main(void) {
    test_uint32( NULL, 0 );
    test_int16( NULL, 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

However, you should really look into the [_Generic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) expression in C11 (not available in C99) as that is probably the closest match to what you want.

Comment: I will require user to typedef types and then this solution will work.

Answer (score -1):

Be explicit about it: Use separate type name and type specification.

```
#define DEFINE_FUNCTION(type, name)                               \
    void Buffer_##name##_Add(size_t idx, type *buffer, type data) \
```

C has very limited toolset for any type generic coding, especially if you are on C99. Better to avoid any trickery, even if it might mean more typing.